# .ns() undefined in google angular maps directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use the angular google maps directive with my app, but I keep getting an "undefined error"

This is my app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['cs'])

.config(['GoogleMapApiProvider'.ns(), function (GoogleMapApi) {
        GoogleMapApi.configure({
            //    key: 'your api key',
        v: '3.17',
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
}])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //routes
}])
```

and my controller

```
angular.module('cs.Controllers')
.controller('MapController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$window', '$document', 'MenuService', 'GoogleMapApi'.ns(),
    function($rootScope, $scope, $window, $document, menuService, GoogleMapApi) {

    $rootScope.menuList = menuService.all();


}]);
```

What could be the problem

Comment: `'GoogleMapApiProvider'` is a string. `'GoogleMapApiProvider'.ns()` calls the `ns` method of the string. I have never heard of a built-in `ns` method, so I'm guessing some library you are using is supposed to add that method (AngularJS does not add it), right? It makes no sense whatsoever to me, but you're the one who wrote the code.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv the code is from the documentation on the site https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api

Comment: Why are you using two .config()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others that got here that had added the missing dependency declaration, see: [angular-google-maps , undefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867638/angular-google-maps-undefined-is-not-a-function/27010736#27010736)

It looks like they've gotten rid of the ns() function, but haven't updated the documentation yet:

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/pull/872/
https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/821

Update all instances of 'string'.ns() to 'uiGmapstring' in your code and you should be good.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the dependency declaration in your app.

```
  angular.module('app', ['google-maps'.ns(),'cs.Controllers']
```

Here's a plunker using one of the project's demo pages. I changed it to use the new provider.
http://plnkr.co/edit/eUbkv2qKu92T9iUp7yAF?p=preview