# angular-google-maps , undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm having some issues to put angular-google-maps working on my website.

After include the needed libraries (googleapis/ lodash.js/ angular-google-maps.min.js), I'm unable to configure the app.

I added 'google-maps' to the app module, like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['iso.directives', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select', 'facebook', 'google-maps'.ns()]);
```

And I received, "undefined is not a function" error.

I'm following the tutorial in https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use

I've seen this ([.ns() undefined in google angular maps directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425345/ns-undefined-in-google-angular-maps-directive)) thread, but doesn't help.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they've gotten rid of the ns() function, but haven't updated the documentation yet:

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/pull/872/
https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/821

Update all instances of 'string'.ns() to 'uiGmapstring' in your code and you should be good.